# regex matching yelling words and emojis in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex for matching a phrases with all letters in upper case

```
private static String ALL_CAPS_REGEXP = "\\b[A-Z\\s]+\\b";
```

but this does not match strings like `;D`, `:P`, `:O` etc.

A few examples are:

- `ALL CAPS :DD REGEXP`
- `ALL CAPS ('-:`
- `ALL CAPS )-': :P`
- `I ALL CAPS REGEXP`

that I want to match. It's something like ignore any character that is not an alphabet but rest should be uppercase

Assume that the alphabets used in any emoji are uppercase only.

What change in the regex I should make to match emoji like strings that have uppercase characters?

Comment: This one worked for those emojis.

Comment: You say "matching a word", but regex is `[A-Z\s]+`, which matches letters and spaces, i.e. matches *multiple* words, not single words. Example: `I said GO HOME` will match `I` and `GO HOME`, not `I`, `GO`, and `HOME`.

Comment: @Andreas You are right about that. I edited that part of the question.

Comment: Is a single-letter uppercase word, e.g. `I`, considered shouting?

Comment: Define "emoji". Anything that might potentially be considered an emoji, so a specific list of recognized emojis, e.g. as listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#Western)?

Comment: @Andreas I have edited the question, I guess it should make more sense now.

Comment: The problem is that some text emojis use lowercase letters, e.g. `:‑p` (tongue sticking out).

Comment: Assume that all alphabets used in any emoji are uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regex *"to match emoji like strings that have uppercase characters"*, we need to declare what "emoji like strings" mean.

Since emojis use (combinations of) various punctuation marks, and you limit to emojis using uppercase letters, you could declare that any combination of punctuation marks and optional uppercase letters is an emoji.

In that case, just list the punctuation marks in the character class.

```
"\\b[A-Z\\s!@#$%^&*()\\_-+={}[\\]:;\"'<>?,./]+\\b"
```

Or maybe more descriptive using [POSIX character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix):

```
"\\b[\\p{Upper}\\p{Space}\\p{Punct}]+\\b"
```

Potentially prefixed by [`(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) for full unicode/international support.

You would probably also want to filter out single-character matches, otherwise an input like `"I rock."` will return `I` and `.`, so use `{2,}` instead of `+`.

```
"(?U)\\b[\\p{Upper}\\p{Space}\\p{Punct}]{2,}\\b"
```

Comment: I just noiced that `\\b[\\p{Upper}\\p{Space}\\p{Punct}]+\\b` also matched `http://url_removed`!!??

Comment: @AnimeshPandey Can't match anything with lowercase letters, so I'm not sure what you are talking about.